# Give number after select dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, dataframe

Hello I have a table like this

```
 Name  Subject Score 
 AA     Math    30
 AA   English   40
 AA     CS      60
 BB     Math    40
 BB   English   55 
 BB     CS      55 
 CC     Math    89
 CC   English   75
 CC     CS      55
```

After selected the Name and Subject I need to give the number to the filtered table
For example Name: AA BB and Subject: Math English was selected. Use pandas condition the table become

```
 Name  Subject Score 
 AA     Math    30
 AA   English   40
 BB     Math    40
 BB   English   55
```

Now, I need to create the number list in order to give a JSON to Web application which my team need the formation like

```
[[0,0,50],[0,1,40],[1,0,40],[1,1,50]]
```

The first variable in list is id for name, the second is id for subject and the third one is score.

In other situation, when Name: BB CC and Subject: English  CS was selected. Use pandas condition the table become

```
 Name  Subject Score 
 BB     English 55
 BB     CS      55
 CC     Math    75
 CC     CS      55
```

In this time  I need to give the number from 0 again to create a new JSON to web application. The table like

```
[[0,0,55],[0,1,55],[1,0,75],[1,1,55]]
```

How could I achieve that and make a JSON always update the  ID number??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is any easy way to do it:

```
data = pandas.DataFrame(table) #your table/data

def my_func(Name):
    #use the set data type to remove duplicates
    names_set = set(data['name'])
    id_number = list(names_set).index(Name) #get the index of the specified name
    return id_number
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me what is Name in the function my_func

Comment: Here, the 'Name' is the name of the person according to your table, for Eg:AA, BB, CC. Let me know if haven't still understood. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'BB', 1: 'BB', 2: 'CC', 3: 'CC'},
 'Subject': {0: 'English', 1: 'CS', 2: 'Math', 3: 'CS'},
 'Score': {0: 55, 1: 55, 2: 75, 3: 55}})


df['nid'] = df['Name'].astype('category').cat.codes
df['sid'] =  df.groupby(['Name']).cumcount()

df[['nid','sid','Score']].values.tolist()
```

Output

```
[[0, 0, 55], [0, 1, 55], [1, 0, 75], [1, 1, 55]]
```